# Graphing x-y coordinates from a mouse with Processing

Tags: mouse, 2d, coordinates, processing

I've found this really cool site on interfacing an Arduino to an optical mouse to read out x-y readings from it. I've done it, and it's working nicely.

Then I was thinking, 'Why not plot all this to become a graph?' and I came across Processing.

I am aware that Processing has an example named 'MouseSignal'

This example is the EXACT thing that I want to write with Processing. But, the only change is that, I want to use the x-y coordinates from the mouse that is attached to the Arduino and ask Processing to generate a 'real-time' graph of the coordinate.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean "MouseSignals", for anyone trying to figure out this question.

Comment: Can you share the website for interfacing Arduino to optical mouse?  That does sounds cool.

Comment: "Can you share the website for interfacing Arduino to optical mouse? That does sounds cool."

Here is it - http://www.synbio.org.uk/component/content/article/46-instrumentation-news/1234-interfacing-an-optical-mouse-sensor-to-your-arduino.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the spot in the code where it says:

```
xvals[width-1] = mouseX; 
yvals[width-1] = mouseY;
```

Replace `mouseX` and `mouseY` with the values coming from the Arduino. You may need to scale these values to fit within the axes.

Comment: I believe I need to add in 

    import processing.serial.*;

at the start as well as 

    println(Serial.list());
      g_serial = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[1], 115200, 'N', 8, 1.0);
     

under void setup?

Comment: If that's how you are getting the data off the Arduino, then yes you would need to do that (and also define Serial g_serial; outside of setup()). Have you looked into the official Arduino processing library instead of just the serial interface, though? http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Processing

Comment: I've looked at it, but don't quite understand, since I haven't tried it. Maybe I'll understand after trying it out. 

And thank you for getting me this far!